# Find a pattern and line of file using python

Tags: python, regex

I have a file.txt which contains lines as:

```
address1:= ("a010")
address2:= ("b005")
address3:= ("b030")
address4:= ("b008")
address5:= ("a002")
address6:= ("b004")
```

I need to match only the number followed by "b" as well as its line as:

```
2: 005
3: 030
4: 008
6: 004
```

Anybody can help me to do that using python?

Comment: show us what you have tried

Comment: "*Anybody can help me to do that using python?*" - Yes, I am certain that many people can help you with that. However, [SO] isn't a help service. It is a question-and-answer forum. Have you attempted to write a program to do this? Do you have a specific programming question to ask? When you get the chance, please take the [tour]. Pay specific attention to [ask].

Answer (score 3):

Code snippet:

```
foo = """
address1:= ("a010")
address2:= ("b005")
address3:= ("b030")
address4:= ("b008")
address5:= ("a002")
address6:= ("b004")
"""
import re
pattern = 'address(\d+):= \("b(.*)"\)'
result = re.findall(pattern, foo)
for item in result:
    print('{index}: {entry}'.format(index=item[0], entry=item[1]))
```

Execution Output:

```
2: 005
3: 030
4: 008
6: 004
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this expression and capture the group 1:

`(?:[b])([0-9]{3})`

Here is a sample:

https://regex101.com/r/fL4csm/2

In the case of using python, i suggest you to try to add some code that you coded instead of asking for how to code it. Check this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic